# PHP I am having difficult passing in a variable to a redirect function I have made

Tags: php, redirect, get

Ok so I have a quick question which I suspect for most is ridiculously easy but here goes...

I have a redirect function

```
function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
if ($location != NULL) {
header("Location: {$location}");
ob_end_flush();
exit;
 }
}
```

But I want to pass in an id variable ($thread_page) into the url, so something like this....

```
  redirect_to("thread.php?id="<?php echo $thread_page; ?>);
```

But this doesn't work....any help?

many thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as how you have done it in your function with `$location`:

```
redirect_to("thread.php?id=$thread_page");
```

You can wrap in curly braces for consistency if you like:

```
redirect_to("thread.php?id={$thread_page}");
```

Also, this looks like `$thread_page` might be an integer, but if you are passing any other types of data it is best to use `urlencode()`.

```
redirect_to("thread.php?id=" . urlencode($thread_page));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be calling redirect_to function from PHP itself, so this should work -

```
 redirect_to("thread.php?id=".$thread_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to('thread.php?id=' . $thread_page);
```